# Loading a website from another doesn't load css

Tags: php, curl

A customer wants to load my website functionalities from his website so I'm creating a php script that uses curl to load my website redirecting all requests to my website, but if the html code seems to be loaded correctly and css files too, the styles insides the css aren't loaded.

I don't see why.

The script:

```
<?php
$uri=preg_replace('#[^a-z0-9_?\./|=]#','',$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']);

set_time_limit(3600);

$cs=curl_init();

curl_setopt($cs, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);    
curl_setopt($cs, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0);
curl_setopt($cs, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 0);

curl_setopt($cs, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, "../some.cookies");
curl_setopt($cs, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, "../some.cookies");

curl_setopt($cs, CURLOPT_HTTPGET, 1);
curl_setopt($cs, CURLOPT_ACCEPT_ENCODING, "gzip");

curl_setopt($cs, CURLOPT_URL, "https://mydomain.tld".$uri);

curl_setopt($cs, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $_POST);
curl_setopt($cs, CURLOPT_POST, count($_POST)>0);

print curl_exec($cs);   

curl_close($cs);
```

Comment: You can find following warning message when you inspect element. `Resource interpreted as Stylesheet but transferred with MIME type text/html: "http://linkall.arcadia.services/base.css?v1536047306".`

Comment: Search for above error message in online to find out how to resolve.

Comment: @SauminiNavaratnam You're right I had to add mime type, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Mime type has to be added, this is the working code:

```
set_time_limit(3600);

$cs=curl_init();

    curl_setopt($cs, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);    
    curl_setopt($cs, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0);
    curl_setopt($cs, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 0);

    curl_setopt($cs, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, "../some.cookies");
    curl_setopt($cs, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, "../some.cookies");

    curl_setopt($cs, CURLOPT_HTTPGET, 1);
    curl_setopt($cs, CURLOPT_ACCEPT_ENCODING, "gzip");

    curl_setopt($cs, CURLOPT_URL, "https://mydomain.tld".$uri);

    curl_setopt($cs, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, http_build_query($_POST));
    curl_setopt($cs, CURLOPT_POST, count($_POST)>0);

    $html=curl_exec($cs);   
    $mime=curl_getinfo($cs, CURLINFO_CONTENT_TYPE);

    header("Content-Type: $mime");
    print $html;

curl_close($cs);
```